# Proof of theorem on Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, asymptotics, approximation

Can someone help prove this theorem? Many thanks!

If $p\to0$ and $n\to\infty$ in such a way that $\lim np = \lambda > 0$, then for  $k=0, 1,\dots$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom nkp^k (1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}$$

Comment: One standard way is to find the limit of the logarithm by applying Stirling's approximation to $\log\binom{n}{k}=\log\Gamma(n+1)-\log\Gamma(n-k+1)-\log(k!).$ Another is to analyze the convergence of the characteristic or cumulant generating functions of the Binomial distribution. There also exist perfectly elementary demonstrations (but they tend to be lengthier). If you're doing this for homework or self-study, then, please indicate what facts you are able to use in the proof, for otherwise you may get answers that are not appropriate for this exercise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261119/intuitively-understand-why-the-poisson-distribution-is-the-limiting-case-of-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the elementary versions follows as below, (a simplified and common version with $\lambda=np$, instead of limiting):
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty
}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}\\&=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty
}\underbrace{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}}_{\rightarrow1}\underbrace{\left(1-{\lambda\over n}\right)^{n}}_{\rightarrow e^{-\lambda}}\underbrace{\left(1-{\lambda\over n}\right)^{-k}}_{\rightarrow1}\end{align}$$

It's a good exercise to show each of these limits.

Comment: I have a problem with the last term, which is $(1-p)^{-k}$, independent of $n$. I do not see it why it should approach 1.

Comment: @F.Tusell $p$ is not independent of $n$ since they should satisfy $pn=\lambda$

Comment: OK, clear enough. I had missed the first bit of the question "If $p\to 0\ldots$". Thank you.

Comment: You assume throughout that $\lambda=np$ but it is only assumed that $\lambda=\lim np.$  The substitution of $\lambda$ for $np$ is not justified, even though it does produce the desired answer.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I've at least noted down in my answer. It's as if the limit sign is hidden in between the words.