# Are these two distributions independent?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, independence

In a [probability cheatsheet](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54bf3241e4b0f0d81bf7ff36/t/55e9494fe4b011aed10e48e5/1441352015658/probability_cheatsheet.pdf), there's the following claim:

[image]

That $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ should be independent seems very unintuitive to me. It seems to me that if $Z_1$ is high, then $Z_2$ is low, and vice-versa. Is there an error in this cheatsheet, and if not, what is wrong with my intuition?

Comment: $Z_1$ will tend to be high in part because $Z$ can be high, in which cases $Z_2$ will simultaneously be high.  For more intuition see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261926/919.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $Z$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are not independent because $Z_1+Z_2=Z$, i.e. there is no conditional independence. But, if we also don't know $Z$, which factor enforces a relationship between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$? e.g. there is no force on $Z_2$ being low when $Z_1$ is high because we also don't know their sum.

Mathematically (let $z=z_1+z_2$), $$\begin{align}P(Z_1=z_1,Z_2=z_2)&=P(Z_1=z_1,Z=z)\\&=P(Z_1=z_1|Z=z)P(Z=z)\\&={z\choose z_1}p^{z_1}(1-p)^{z-z_1}e^{-\lambda}\lambda^z/z!\\&=\frac{1}{z_1!z_2!}(\lambda p)^{z_1}(\lambda(1-p)^{z_2})e^{-\lambda p}e^{-\lambda(1-p)}\\&=P(Z_1=z_1)P(Z_2=z_2)\end{align}$$